# VS Code snippet - Only keep filename before first dot

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I want to keep only the word before the first dot:

```
user.entity.ts
```

Current code:

```
${TM_FILENAME_BASE/([^.]+)/${1:/upcase}/}
```

Unfortunately, this does only transforms the first part, rather than split it out:

```
USER.entity
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use this:

`"body": ["${TM_FILENAME_BASE/([^.]+).*/${1:/upcase}/}"],`

the idea being that your version kept the `entity` part because it wasn't part of the match - the middle part `([^.]+)` in your snuippet.

Since it wasn't part of the match it goes through unchanged, as it should.  So I made it part of the match

`([^.]+).*`

and now since it isn't part of the replacement, it will be removed.